# URLConnection empty stream

Tags: c#, android, url, xamarin, urlconnection

URLConnection Stream is Empty

I'm working with Xamarin Studio 4.0.9 and use this code:

```
Stream lResult = null;

URLConnection lConn = new URL(url).OpenConnection();

lResult = lConn.InputStream;

return lResult;
```

To get a Stream from this url: http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=52.37,9.74&daddr=52.370100224,9.739360256&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=dragdir
Since a few weaks it doesn't work anymore and the stream is empty, when I read from it.
Has anyone an idea why?

**UPDATE**

I also tried this:

```
Uri lUri=new Uri(url);

WebRequest request=(WebRequest) WebRequest.Create(lUri); 

request.Method="GET";

WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();

lResult=response.GetResponseStream();
```

but I got this exception:
System.Net.WebException Error getting response stream (Write: EndWrite failure): SendFailure

**NOTE**

The application is made with c# in Xamarin Studio 4.0.9

Answer (score 0):

let's consult this example

```
URL url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=52.37,9.74&daddr=52.370100224,9.739360256&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=dragdir");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);//call function to read a stream
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. I have to say that the application is in c#.

Comment: i saw you add to Android term, ok, let's consult my new answer

Answer (score 0):

this is my util class

```
 public class HttpConnection
    {
        public static string GetString(string url)
        {
            return GetString(url, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        public static string GetString(string url, Encoding encode)
        {
            HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            oReq.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5";
            oReq.Method = "GET";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();
            StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encode);
            String s = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
            loResponseStream.Close();

            return s.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
        }
}
```

let's call function HttpConnection.GetString(string url) like this

```
HttpConnection.GetString("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=52.37,9.74&daddr=52.370100224,9.739360256&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=dragdir")
```

Comment: I got this exception:
Sytem.Net.WebException
Error getting response stream (Write: EndWrite failure): SendFailure

Comment: it work for all my application, i've just tested and result = {tooltipHtml:" (26 m / 2 secs)",polylines:[{id:"route0",points:"yns~H}fmz@i@X",levels:"BB",numLevels:4,zoomFactor:16}]}

Comment: I wish I would get that too :(

Comment: i guess your computer filter and drop some package, let's turn off firewall or other security programs or try this app in another computer

Comment: maybe it's a problem with XamarinStudio because it worked before and nothing changed with my computer or in the code...

Comment: if you are a .NET developer, let's use Visual Studio for develop the application. This is a best of IDE for .NET developer

Comment: It's a application for Android phone. I think I can't do this with Visual Studio.